# Dimension of $c/c_0$

Tags: functional-analysis, analysis, lp-spaces

Be defined...
\begin{align*}
&c_0:=\{x:=(x_n)_{n\in \mathbb{N}}, x_k \in \mathbb{R}: \lim_{n\rightarrow \infty} x_n = 0\}\\
&c:=\{x:=(x_n)_{n\in \mathbb{N}}, x_k \in \mathbb{R}: \lim_{n\rightarrow \infty} x_n \quad \text{exists}\}
\end{align*}
in $l^{\infty}$-norm

Prove that $\dim(c/c_0)=1$

---

My Idea:

I want to find out what's $\dim(c/c_0)$ whereas $c/c_0$ is the [quotient space](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Quotient_space_(linear_algebra)). Meaning: $c/c_0:=\{[v]: v\in c\}$ and $[v]:=\{w\in c: \underbrace{v\sim w}_{(v-w) \in c_0}\}$

Since I'm presumably in subspaces $c_0,c$ of $l^{\infty}$, I'm not sure if I can even find a basis of $c$ or $c_0$ since $l^{\infty}$ doesn't really have a base in classical sense (I think?)

---

So I'd like to prove it with Rank-nullity-theorem: Let $f:V\rightarrow W$ linear map. Then: $\dim(V)=\dim\ker(f)+\dim \text{im}(f)$.

Let $f:c/c_0\rightarrow \mathbb{R}$ be defined as $v\mapsto\lim_{n\rightarrow \infty} v_n$.

Proof that it's linear:

1. Show $f(\lambda v)=\lambda f(v) \Rightarrow f(\lambda v) =\lim_{n\rightarrow \infty}\lambda v_n=\lambda \lim_{n\rightarrow \infty}v_n=\lambda f(v)$
2. Show $f(v+w)=f(v)+f(w)\Rightarrow f(v+w) = \lim_{n\rightarrow \infty} u_n+w_n = \lim_{n\rightarrow \infty}u_n + \lim_{n\rightarrow \infty}w_n=f(v)+f(u)$

Now obviously, the kernel of this map is the zero-class $[0]$ since $f([0]) = 0$, which means that $\dim\ker(f)=0$.

The image is then all real numbers i.e. $f(c/c_0)=\mathbb{R}$ and $\dim \text{im}(f) = \dim(\mathbb{R}) = 1$.

Rank-nullity-theorem gives us $\dim(c/c_0)=1+0 = 1$

Is that proof correct? Thanks in advance for any useful input.

Comment: in order to use the Rank-nullity-theorem, you have to show that $\dim c/c_0$ is finite...

Comment: @EvangelopoulosF. You sure? I learned that it also holds true for infinite dimensional spaces. The German wikipedia says so too. The English wikipedia does indeed need finite dimensions. Maybe an error in the English wikipedia?

Comment: Well if $f:V\to W$ is injective, then $\dim V \leq \dim W$, so I guess $\dim c/c_0$ is finite.

Comment: @EvangelopoulosF. yeah that's true. Also, do you know what's the base of $l^{\infty}$? There are people that say it has no base in classic sense.

Comment: well in general Hamel basis is not of much interest in infinite dimensional Banach spaces (an infinite dimensional Banach space has an uncountable Hamel basis). There is another nothing of basis, called the Shauder basis. It is known that the sequence $(e_n)_{n \geq 1}$ where $e_n(k) = 1 $ if $k=n$ and $0$ otherwise is a Schauder basis for $l^p$

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to be more careful with the details:

- $f$ maps the *equivalence class* of $v = (v_n)_{n \in \mathbb N} \in c$ to the real number $f([v]) := \lim_n v_n$. In particular, one needs to ask itself why $f$ is well-defined, that is, if $[v] = [w]$ (i.e. $v \sim w$) then $f([v]) = f([w])$?
- Sure, linearity of $f$ follows from the limit rules, *but also* follows from the definition of the operations in $c/c_0$: $[v]+[w] := [v+w]$ and $\lambda[v] := [\lambda v]$.
- The kernel is $\{[0]\}$, but not for the reason that you gave. If $f([v]) = 0$, then $v \in c_0$ and so $v \sim 0$, meaning $[v]=[0]$.
- Surjectivity of $f$ is easy to prove, so you can avoid the rank-nullity theorem by concluding that $f$ is an isomorphism, and then $c/c_0 \cong \mathbb R$ as $\mathbb R$-vector spaces.

A more clean approach is by using the [first isomorphism theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Isomorphism_theorems#Theorem_A_(modules)):

> Consider $\varphi : c \to \mathbb R$ given by $\varphi(v) = \lim_n v_n$. Then by the limit rules, $\varphi$ is linear, and since $\varphi$ is surjective, it follows that $c/(\ker \varphi) \cong \mathbb R$, but $\ker \varphi = c_0$.

Answer (score 2):

Using the Rank-nullity Theorem is technically correct, but it is kind of bad form. You are using it to hide information you already have.

The function $f$ you constructed is already a vector space isomorphism between $c/c_0$ and $\mathbb R$. Since the rank is finite, it is automatically bounded, so you get the isomorphism as Banach spaces (which RN does not give you). And with very little more effort you can show that $f$ is isometric, so you get that $c/c_0$ and $\mathbb R$ are isometrically isomorphic. And you get for free that they are isometrically isomorphic as Banach algebras, since your $f$ is also multiplicative.

Answer (score 1):

Hint:

Any $\boldsymbol{x}\in\mathcal{c}$ can be expressed as
$$\mathbf{x}=\big(\boldsymbol{x}-\lim_n\boldsymbol{x}(n)\,\cdot\boldsymbol{u}\big) +\lim_n\boldsymbol{x}(n)\,\cdot\boldsymbol{u}
$$
where $\boldsymbol{u}(n)=1$ for all $n$. The term
$$
\boldsymbol{y}=\boldsymbol{x}-\lim_n\boldsymbol{x}(n)\,\cdot\boldsymbol{u}\in\mathcal{c}_0
$$
This shows that $\mathcal{c}/\mathcal{c}_0$ is generated by the coset $\boldsymbol{u}+\mathcal{c}_0$; that is, $\operatorname{dim}\big(\mathcal{c}/\mathcal{c}_0\big)=1$.